# Blocking directory listing on a wamp server

Tags: apache-2.2, html, directory-listing

So I have a website that runs through wamp however if you type a path in the address bar, you get an index of the directory, which I don't want

I have already tried to add a `.htaccess` file in the directory to stop it indexing (saying `IgnoreIndex *`) and went into the apache `httpd.conf` file and changing

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
```

to:

```
# Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
```

however none have worked... I have tried restarting my server, restarting services, but nothing... Help?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a line

```
Options -Indexes
```

in your configuration, either via `.htaccess` or the `httpd.conf`.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options